# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vuforia.VuforiaUnityPlayer.VuforiaInitializer

Tags: java, android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

my application is about running the android app and on button click it should go to unity activity and place the object on ground plane based on the object name passed by android activity here's the error that i'm getting while running.

```
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vuforia.VuforiaUnityPlayer.VuforiaInitializer
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:453)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:378)
            at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.nativeRender(Native Method)
            at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer.c(Unknown Source:23)
            at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e$2.queueIdle(Unknown Source:94)
            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:395)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:160)
            at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayer$e.run(Unknown Source:48)
```

here is the gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test2"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation project(':GroundPlaneDetection')
}
```

here's main activity code

```
Button b;
        b = findViewById(R.id.hello);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, UnityPlayerActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("arguments", "kitchen_stool");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

here i've imported aar file of the unity and that works fine but i'm getting this error please help
thanks in advance.

Comment: There is a solution for this issue on vuforia's forum. https://developer.vuforia.com/forum/android/androidjavaexception-javalangclassnotfoundexception-comvuforiavuforiaunityplayervuforiainitializer-error

Comment: yeah i've already seen that and it doesn't work

Comment: @VishwaArdeshna, did you succeed ?